# Count the categories from particular one column in using ADF(azure data factory)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, expressionbuilder

I have data in which  it has one column named category. Categories are chair and table.

- But Issue is that I want to to perform count for table,chair  and two  more categories bowl and plat which is not present in my data.
- I want to get count for those all 4 categories from data. If not found that category it should write zero for its count. So how to do that in adf?

I have tried to do filtering, derived column but derived column give me additional column but i want it at row level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the remaining values doesn't exists in the column, Dataflow can't give the count for those.

So, you can follow below approach to achieve your requirement. In this approach, you need an array containing values of all categories like `['chair','table','bowl','plat']`.

**This is starting data that I am taking in the dataflow source:**

```
category
chair
table
chair
table
table
chair
chair
table
```

First use an **aggregate** transformation to get the category and count columns.

Give `category` column in the **Group by** section and create a new column `count` with `count(category)` expression  in the **aggregate** section like below.

[image]

It will give the result with existing values.

[image]

Now, take another **aggregate** transformation after this. In this, leave **group by section empty** and in the **aggregate** section, create a column for an array of existing categories using `collect(category)` expression.

[image]

It will produce below results.

[image]

Next, take a **derived column** transformation and create two columns using the above `original` array column and the array of all categories.

```
rem_items - toString(unfold(except(['chair','table','bowl','plat'],original)))

count2 - 0
```

[image]

This will first generate an array of non-existing categories and unfolds that array as rows. Those will be converted to string type column like below. Coming to `count2` columns, whatever the values that are coming from this transformation, the count for those will be `0` only.

[image]

Now, use a **select** transformation and remove the extra `original` column.

[image]

As a result, select transformation will only contains two columns.

Now, create a **New branch** after the **aggregate1** transformation and add a **Union** transformation to it. Use the above **select1** transformation as another input and do the **union by position**.

[image]

This will give the desired result.

[image]

Add your sink to the union transformation and you can run the dataflow.